# How to display a loading message in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.Forms in which I need loading message. How can I display the loading message?

Code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Padding="30" >
  <Grid>
   //something
  </Grid>
  </StackLayout>
  <ContentView x:Name="overlay" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="10, 0">
    <ActivityIndicator  WidthRequest="110" HeightRequest="70" IsRunning="True" IsVisible="True" Color="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
  </ContentView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

Set `IsVisible="True"` for ContentView will show you the ActivityIndicator.

```
<ContentView x:Name="overlay" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="10, 0">
    <ActivityIndicator  WidthRequest="110" HeightRequest="70" IsRunning="True" IsVisible="True" Color="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
  </ContentView>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM and want full modal Loading Messages look at [ACR User Dialogs for Xamarin and Windows](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs). You can install it via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/). You can find the sample application [here](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/tree/master/src/Samples).